# Disable security in springBootTest using WebTestClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

SpringBoot in 2.1 Release Notes contain the following piece of information:

> Security configuration is now applied to WebTestClient. For more information on testing secured endpoints, please refer to the relevant section of Spring Security’s reference documentation.

Problem:

After updating SpringBoot from **2.0.4** to **2.1.2** I found that my tests have stopped to work. I am using `@SpringBootTest` for my REST test. My `WebTestClient` cannot reach server. I did try a lot (e.g. from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/html5/#test-method-setup))
to mock or disable security and still getting `403 FORBIDDEN` response.

Do you have any clues what can be wrong?

I create `WebTestClient` in the following way:

```
client = WebTestClient
  .bindToServer()
  .baseUrl("http://localhost:$port")
  .build()
```

Also tried to exclude `SecurityAutoConfiguration.class`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some dark place, deep down the rabbit hole I found this:

```
@TestConfiguration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration
  implements WebSecurityConfigurer<WebSecurity> {

  @Override
  public void init(WebSecurity builder) throws Exception {
    builder.ignoring().requestMatchers(
      new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity builder) throws Exception {
  }

}
```

Remember to register class in `@SpringBootTest`, for instance:

```
@SpringBootTest(
  classes = [SomeApplication, SecurityConfiguration],
  webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT
)
```

It's not disabling spring security, but it makes it transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the [AutoConfigureMockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/AutoConfigureMockMvc.html#addFilters()) annotation in the test class.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false) // to ignore security
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to specify a mock user to test with?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/authentication.html

Comment: Yes, if the application has role-based authorization.

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround for similar problem by setting `secure` flag to `false` for `@WebMvcTest`.

Like:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SomeController.class, secure = false)
```